# Is my intuition about polynomial ring correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have a hard time understanding the idea of quotient ring, but first I think I need to clarify some things.

1. When we write $\mathbb{Z_2}[X]$ what we mean is the set $\{1,x,1+x\}$ ?
2. when we write $ \mathbb Z_2[X]/<X^2+1>$ that's equal to $a + <x^2+1> $ for every $a \in \mathbb Z_2[X]$, which is the set $\{1+x^2+1,x+x^2+1,1+x+x^2+1\}$ ?

I think  most of the things I wrote is wrong, but that's my current intuition and understanding of these things. Can someone clarify this for me?

How you guys  think intuitive about these things, like what's on your mind when you see $ \mathbb Z_2[X]/<X^2+1>$  ?

Comment: 1. No, we mean every polynomial $a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots +a_0$ with coefficients in $\Bbb Z/2$. This is the polynomial ring $R[X]$ for a ring $R$. So 2. is also not correct. Where is the zero polynomial, by the way?

Comment: @DietrichBurde  But in $\mathbb{Z_2}$ isn't $ x^3+1=x+1$  because $3=1$ in mod2 or this doesn't affect the powers ?

Comment: No, not the powers, only the coefficients in the ring $R$. Look up again the definition of a polynomial ring $R[X]$. Here $R=\Bbb Z/2$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  Then I don't get how we say $ |\mathbb{Z_2}[x] / <x^3+x+1>|=2^3$

Comment: The quotient is a field with $8$ elements, yes. We identify all polynomials modulo $x^3+x+1$, in the same way as we identify all integers modulo $2$ in $\Bbb Z/2$. Also here, look again at the quotient ring, how it is really defined. So $x^3$ is identified with $x+1$, say.

Comment: @PetrosK In order not to get confused about this, it is good to know how to formally define polynomials. A polynomial in $R[x]$ may be defined as a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $R$ with finite support, i.e it is equal to zero for all but finitely many values. If $f$ is such a function and we have $f(0)=a_0, f(1)=a_1,..., f(n)=a_n$ and the other values are zeroes then we denote it by $f=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$. So the power $3$ in $x^3$ is a natural number, it has nothing to do with the element $3$ in $\mathbb{Z_2}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Can I think of $\mathbb{Z_2}[x] $ as the set of all the  polynomials with coefficient 1 ?

Comment: Yes, but coefficients $0$ or $1$, and they add according to $1+1=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's useful to think of the quotient $R/I$ as something like "the same ring $R$, but where anything in $I$ is set to zero." When the context is clear, most people will omit the coset notation and use the same notation $x$ to mean $x\in R$ and also $x+I\in R/I$.

The notation $R[x]$ is usually read "$R$ adjoined $x$," and it just means polynomials in $x$ with coefficients in $R$. So if $\Bbb Z_2$ is the ring with underlying set $\{0,1\}$, elements of $\Bbb Z_2[x]$ look like
$$x^5+x^3+x^2+1\qquad\text{or}\qquad 1+x+x^{10}.$$
Note that $0$ and $1$ are also in $\Bbb Z_2[x]$.

Elements of $\Bbb Z_2[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ are (basically) all of the same polynomials, but with the added condition that $x^2+1=0$. However, this means we have a lot of duplicates. Any polynomial with $x^3$, for example, can be written as a lower degree polynomial. In fact, since $x^2+1=0$ and the coefficients are in $\Bbb Z_2$, we have $x^2=1$. So, for example,
$$x^5+x^3+x^2+1=\left(x^2\right)\left(x^2\right)x+\left(x^2\right)x+x^2+1=x+x+1+1=0.$$

Also
$$1+x+x^{10}=1+x+\left(x^2\right)^5=1+x+1=x.$$

In effect, we see that the only polynomials which are actually unique are $0$, $1$, $x$, and $x+1$.

Comment: That's a very nice and simple explanation, thanks a lot Elliot.